# addEventListener for multiple dynamic generated elements

Tags: javascript, dom, dynamic, onload, addeventlistener

For using code in a chrome app I need to switch from `onclick` to `addEventListener`.

I dynamically add some img's to the DOM. I and want to execute a resize function when clicked on an imgBox. With `onclick` it worked. But with my new way only the last added imgBox have a working eventlistener. Why?

```
function addImgBox (baseImgUrl, id) {

   var imgBoxHtml = "<div id='box-"+id+"'><img id='img-" + id + "' src='" + baseImgUrl + id + ".ipg'></div>"

   document.getElementById("insert-loding-ImgBoxes-here").innerHTML += imgBoxHtml;
   var loadImg = document.getElementById('img-' + id); // catching the new img element

   loadImg.onload = function() {

      ... moving the imgbox to an other place in DOM here ...

      document.getElementById('box-' + id).addEventListener("click", function(event) {
         fullsize(id); 
      },false);

   }
}

addImgBox('image_no_',1);
addImgBox('image_no_',2);
addImgBox('image_no_',3);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change innerHTML browser removes all child nodes and inserts new children without event listeners

Comment: Great! Many thanks. I searched many hours for the reason. I always thought setting the event listener will not work, or it will be overwritten be the new listener. But had no idea that i have to care about insertHTML instead. :)

Comment: somebody sad this is  was bad question. is it? why? i have not found the solution, with searching because i was not seeing the source of the problem. i would say, this is a good reason to ask a question.

Comment: @Lutz Maybe they thought you should spell-check your question title.

Comment: @torazaburo: if this is the reason, some people here are crazy. i'm no native english speaker. is there still a typo? (I have still corrected: multible).

Comment: @Mi Ke Bu: I have changed now from insertHTML to `document.getElementById("insert-loding-ImgBoxes-here").appendChild(imgBoxHtml)`. After using `createElement` to generate the outer div of `imgBoxHtml`. But the problem is still there! Why?